# Inserting large number of rows into sqlite db using php

Tags: php, sqlite

I have the below php code that works fine with 10000-20000 lines, but if I need to insert say 300000000 (300k) lines o course php will time out or the client will close the tab.
Any advice how to improve the code? The below code is just a part of the script.

```
$db = new SQLite3('my.db');
$db->busyTimeout(5000);
$db->exec("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;");
if($q == 'obserations' && isset($_POST['obserations'])){
$van = $db->query("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master;");
    while($array = $van->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
        $mytables = trim($array['name']);

        $mylines = trim($_POST['obserations']);
        $mylines = explode("\r\n", $mylines);
        $count = 0;
        while(!empty($mylines[$count])){
            $new_obs = $mylines[$count];
            $new_obs = SQLite3::escapeString(htmlentities($new_obs, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            if(!$db->querySingle("SELECT * FROM '$mytables' WHERE obs = '$new_obs';")){
                if(preg_match("~^http://$mytables/.*$~", $new_obs, $matches)){
                    $db->exec("INSERT INTO '$mytables' (obs, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES ('$new_obs', '', '', '', '', '');");
                }
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please add example input data (`$_POST['obserations']`?) and your table specifications.

Comment: @timclutton Example of input data: `http://sometablename/observation-nr1`

Comment: @timclutton So, for each table in sqlite db we insert some new lines . The above code does first match the table name in each line, and if line does match with any table name it goes to corresponding table and insert the new line

Comment: Show the table definition! Do you have any indexes?

Comment: @CL. I don't understand where you want to get. The above code is all there is